# Does a Draconic Ancestry Sorcerer's Elemental Affinity apply to a Dragonborn's Breath Weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, sorcerer, breath-weapon, pregenerated-characters

I'm asking this after looking at the pregen characters on the Wizard's website.
http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/character_sheets

The first one, the Dragonborn Sorcerer, gains Elemental Affinity at 6th Level. And this damage is immediately applied to his Breath Weapon.

Based on the rules as written in the book, and even as they are written on the pregen character sheet, I can't see how this is correct. Unless the Breath Weapon somehow counts as a spell.

Is this correct? Should a Sorcerer apply his Elemental Affinity damage to his breath weapon? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're correct, Elemental Affinity applies specifically to spells.

> Starting at 6th level, when you **cast a spell** that deals damage of the type associated with your draconic ancestry, add your Charisma modifier to that damage.

This is probably just an oversight on the part of whoever wrote the character sheet.

With that said, the DM is free to rule that this works, and it's a pretty cool and reasonable idea. I'd certainly allow it if one of my players took the same dragon type for both their Dragonborn race and their Draconic Sorcerer.

Answer (score 6):

By RAW, no it does not apply, as Breath Weapon is an ability, not a spell. Elemental Affinity states:

> when you **cast a spell** that deals damage of the type associated with your draconic heritage